# FileLock with Tomcat Server and BlazeDS

Tags: tomcat, locking, blazeds

i have a tomcat/blazeDS application in with several users write to the same xml file. while they write i want to have a file lock on that file. my first attempt was to get the filechannel of the file and establish a lock() to the file. But unfortunately there is always a OverlappingFileLockException if i try to do so cause there is always a new process for a new call to the blazeDS components.

Is there a possibility to store a FileLock within a session or a basic functionality of tomcat to lock files within a session.

Thnak you all

Comment: It would help if you can describe what are you trying to achieve (to prevent concurrent access to the file or to prevent concurrent writes etc)

Comment: I solved it by using a ReentrentLock within a static class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a ReentrentLock within a static class so i cannot access it while it is locked.

```
public class DataAccessUtil {

private static final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
```

...

```
public static void lockDataFolder() {

    lock.lock();  // block until condition holds
}

public static void unlockDataFolder() {

    lock.unlock(); 

}
```